# Docker Permissions issue accessing `/dev/dri` Device

Tags: permissions, docker, devices, docker-compose

I have a permissions problem. I am running [Photoprism](https://www.photoprism.app/) inside a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) container on Ubuntu 22.04. I want to use Intel QuickSync hardware transcoding. To do this, the app needs to access the `/dev/dri` device. I am attempting to get the app running without using `priviledged: true` in the docker-compose file. It works (ie, the app is able to use `/dev/dri`) when using `priviledged: true`.  When I remove `priviledged: true`, the app reports this, even though `devices:\n - /dev/dri` is in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
...
 ⠿ Container photoprism-photoprism-1  Starting                                                                                                                             1.9s 
Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/dri": no such file or directory
```

Currently I have [Plex](https://www.plex.tv/) installed natively (ie, not using Docker), and it works with `/dev/dri` just fine.

Here are the permissions on `/dev/dri`:

```
$ ls -al /dev/dri
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root        100 May 29 14:09 .
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root       5200 May 29 14:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root         80 May 29 14:09 by-path
crw-rw----+  1 root render 226,   0 May 29 14:09 card0
crw-rw----+  1 root render 226, 128 May 29 14:09 renderD128
```

(`render` is a group name, but what is the meaning of `226,` in the listing output?)

Here are the details of the `plex` user (which is the user which is running `plexmediaserver`, which is working with `/dev/dri`):

```
$ id plex
uid=998(plex) gid=998(plex) groups=998(plex),44(video),109(render)
```

...and the user which is running `docker-compose up -d`

```
$ id myuser
uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare)
```

I thought that since the `plex` user is working fine with `/dev/dri`, maybe I could use the `plex` user with Photoprism as well. But I was unable to get it working:

```
   # inside docker compose
   user: "998:998"
```

The relevant parts of the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  photoprism:
    image: photoprism/photoprism:latest
    ...
    ## Start as non-root user before initialization (supported: 0, 33, 50-99, 500-600, and 900-1200):
    user: "998:998"
    ## Share hardware devices with FFmpeg and TensorFlow (optional):
    devices:
      - "/dev/dri:/dev/dri"                         # Intel QSV
    ...
```

TL;DR:
Works when I use docker privileged mode, doesn't work otherwise. Also, I could use some help understanding `ls` output which mysteriously includes an unexplained `226,` in it (See above `ls` output).

Answer (score 0):

I went through similar problem with my QNAP TS-251b and photoprism.
Following docker cmd worked for me:

```
sudo docker run -d --device=/dev/dri photoprism
```

I've also contacted QNAP support regarding device mapping problem and they gave me following steps for mapping(creating) dri device(to be executed in container):

```
mkdir /dev/dri
mknod /dev/dri/card0 c 226 0
mknod /dev/dri/renderD128 c 226 128
chmod 666 /dev/dri/card0
chmod 666 /dev/dri/renderD128
```

Hope it helps.